# How to check if vMotion is configured in RedHat Linux 7.2?

Tags: linux, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, esxi

We have a couple of RedHat Linux machines

We not sure that vMotion is configured.

Is it possible to identify if vmotion vMotion configured, from the  RedHat OS itself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 options from many :

### Via a script.

1. Save the above script on all ESXi hosts that will share the hypervisor hostname with the VM (`setGuestInfo.sh`).

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   IFS=$'\n'
   for VM in $(vmware-cmd -l);
   do
           VM_STATE=$(vmware-cmd "${VM}" getstate | awk -F "= " '{print $2}')
           if [ "${VM_STATE}" == "on" ]; then
                   echo "Setting info for ${VM}"
                   vmware-cmd "${VM}" setguestinfo hypervisor.hostname "$(hostname)"
           fi
   done
   unset IFS
   ```
2. Set a cron job so the script will be executed every minute on each ESXi host.

   ```
   0 * * * * /vmfs/volume/shared-storage/setGuestInfo.sh
   ```
3. Now on the VM, save the above script to get the value of the variable `hypervisor.hostname` (`getGuestInfo.sh`).

   ```
   vmtoolsd --cmd  "info-get guestinfo.hypervisor.hostname"
   ```
4. Set a cron job so you will get the host info every minute.

   ```
   0 * * * * getGuestInfo.sh >> /tmp/vmotion.txt
   ```

   The output will be like:

   ```
   Based on `/tmp/vmotion.txt` 

   Esx1

   Esx2

   Esx2

   Esx1

   Esx1

   Esx1

   Esx3
   ```
5. Set another script that will detect the vMotion once the previous value on `/tmp/vmotion.txt` has changed (`checkVmotion.sh`)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   last="$( tail -n 1 /tmp/vmotion.txt )"
   previous="$( tail -n 2 /tmp/vmotion.txt | head -1 )"
   if [ "$last" != "$previous" ] ; then
     echo Vmotion
   fi
   ```
6. Set it as cron job.

   ```
   0 * * * * checkVmotion.sh
   ```

Now you can use the output at your convenience.

### Via vCenter API

1. Make sure Python is installed.
2. Install "[pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/virtual_machine_device_info.py)" SDK as it facilitates API calls.

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pyvmomi
   ```
3. Get your VM UUID.

   ```
   dmidecode -t system | grep UUID
   ```
4. Get your VM main IP.
5. Use this [sample](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/virtual_machine_device_info.py) & customize it (delete args, set constants for host password port uuid ip ) - you should have admin access on vCenter Red.
6. Set a cron job so you will get the host info every minute.

   ```
   0 * * * * python getGuestInfo.py >> /tmp/vmotion.txt
   ```
7. Repeat 5,6 steps from the first method.

Hope it should help.